# Hazelcast 3.5.2 NATIVE in-memory-format

Tags: java, hazelcast

I would like to use Hazelcast 3.5.2 **High-Density Memory Store** feature. However, I could not make it work.

Following Hazelcast document, I configure my Hazelcast server.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--
  ~ Copyright (c) 2008-2015, Hazelcast, Inc. All Rights Reserved.
  ~
  ~ Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
  ~ you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
  ~ You may obtain a copy of the License at
  ~
  ~ http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
  ~
  ~ Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
  ~ distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
  ~ WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
  ~ See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
  ~ limitations under the License.
  -->

<!--
    The default Hazelcast configuration. This is used when:

    - no hazelcast.xml if present

-->
<hazelcast xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.hazelcast.com/schema/config hazelcast-config-3.5.xsd"
           xmlns="http://www.hazelcast.com/schema/config"
           xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <group>
        <name>dev</name>
        <password>dev-pass</password>
    </group>
    <license-key>HazelcastEnterprise#10Nodes#HDMemory:10GB#bjERNiaUAyS1V7IOl530KTrf13W4x30oz1Q010909911h090MQ00100060gL</license-key>
    <management-center enabled="true">http://192.168.56.120:8080/mancenter-3.5.2</management-center>
    <network>
        <port auto-increment="true" port-count="100">5701</port>
        <outbound-ports>
            <!--
            Allowed port range when connecting to other nodes.
            0 or * means use system provided port.
            -->
            <ports>0</ports>
        </outbound-ports>
        <join>
            <multicast enabled="true">
                <multicast-group>224.2.2.3</multicast-group>
                <multicast-port>54327</multicast-port>
            </multicast>
            <tcp-ip enabled="false">
                <interface>127.0.0.1</interface>
                <member-list>
                    <member>127.0.0.1</member>
                </member-list>
            </tcp-ip>
            <aws enabled="false">
                <access-key>my-access-key</access-key>
                <secret-key>my-secret-key</secret-key>
                <!--optional, default is us-east-1 -->
                <region>us-west-1</region>
                <!--optional, default is ec2.amazonaws.com. If set, region shouldn't be set as it will override this property -->
                <host-header>ec2.amazonaws.com</host-header>
                <!-- optional, only instances belonging to this group will be discovered, default will try all running instances -->
                <security-group-name>hazelcast-sg</security-group-name>
                <tag-key>type</tag-key>
                <tag-value>hz-nodes</tag-value>
            </aws>
        </join>
        <interfaces enabled="true">
            <interface>192.168.56.1</interface>
        </interfaces>
        <ssl enabled="false"/>
        <socket-interceptor enabled="false"/>
        <symmetric-encryption enabled="false">
            <!--
               encryption algorithm such as
               DES/ECB/PKCS5Padding,
               PBEWithMD5AndDES,
               AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding,
               Blowfish,
               DESede
            -->
            <algorithm>PBEWithMD5AndDES</algorithm>
            <!-- salt value to use when generating the secret key -->
            <salt>thesalt</salt>
            <!-- pass phrase to use when generating the secret key -->
            <password>thepass</password>
            <!-- iteration count to use when generating the secret key -->
            <iteration-count>19</iteration-count>
        </symmetric-encryption>
    </network>
    <partition-group enabled="false"/>
    <executor-service name="default">
        <pool-size>16</pool-size>
        <!--Queue capacity. 0 means Integer.MAX_VALUE.-->
        <queue-capacity>0</queue-capacity>
    </executor-service>
    <queue name="default">
        <!--
            Maximum size of the queue. When a JVM's local queue size reaches the maximum,
            all put/offer operations will get blocked until the queue size
            of the JVM goes down below the maximum.
            Any integer between 0 and Integer.MAX_VALUE. 0 means
            Integer.MAX_VALUE. Default is 0.
        -->
        <max-size>0</max-size>
        <!--
            Number of backups. If 1 is set as the backup-count for example,
            then all entries of the map will be copied to another JVM for
            fail-safety. 0 means no backup.
        -->
        <backup-count>1</backup-count>

        <!--
            Number of async backups. 0 means no backup.
        -->
        <async-backup-count>0</async-backup-count>

        <empty-queue-ttl>-1</empty-queue-ttl>
    </queue>
    <map name="default">
        <!--
           Data type that will be used for storing recordMap.
           Possible values:
           BINARY (default): keys and values will be stored as binary data
           OBJECT : values will be stored in their object forms
           NATIVE : values will be stored in non-heap region of JVM
        -->
        <in-memory-format>NATIVE</in-memory-format>

        <!--
            Number of backups. If 1 is set as the backup-count for example,
            then all entries of the map will be copied to another JVM for
            fail-safety. 0 means no backup.
        -->
        <backup-count>1</backup-count>
        <!--
            Number of async backups. 0 means no backup.
        -->
        <async-backup-count>0</async-backup-count>
        <!--
            Maximum number of seconds for each entry to stay in the map. Entries that are
            older than <time-to-live-seconds> and not updated for <time-to-live-seconds>
            will get automatically evicted from the map.
            Any integer between 0 and Integer.MAX_VALUE. 0 means infinite. Default is 0.
        -->
        <time-to-live-seconds>0</time-to-live-seconds>
        <!--
            Maximum number of seconds for each entry to stay idle in the map. Entries that are
            idle(not touched) for more than <max-idle-seconds> will get
            automatically evicted from the map. Entry is touched if get, put or containsKey is called.
            Any integer between 0 and Integer.MAX_VALUE. 0 means infinite. Default is 0.
        -->
        <max-idle-seconds>0</max-idle-seconds>
        <!--
            Valid values are:
            NONE (no eviction),
            LRU (Least Recently Used),
            LFU (Least Frequently Used).
            NONE is the default.
        -->
        <eviction-policy>NONE</eviction-policy>
        <!--
            Maximum size of the map. When max size is reached,
            map is evicted based on the policy defined.
            Any integer between 0 and Integer.MAX_VALUE. 0 means
            Integer.MAX_VALUE. Default is 0.
        -->
        <max-size policy="PER_NODE">0</max-size>
        <!--
            When max. size is reached, specified percentage of
            the map will be evicted. Any integer between 0 and 100.
            If 25 is set for example, 25% of the entries will
            get evicted.
        -->
        <eviction-percentage>25</eviction-percentage>
        <!--
            Minimum time in milliseconds which should pass before checking
            if a partition of this map is evictable or not.
            Default value is 100 millis.
        -->
        <min-eviction-check-millis>100</min-eviction-check-millis>
        <!--
            While recovering from split-brain (network partitioning),
            map entries in the small cluster will merge into the bigger cluster
            based on the policy set here. When an entry merge into the
            cluster, there might an existing entry with the same key already.
            Values of these entries might be different for that same key.
            Which value should be set for the key? Conflict is resolved by
            the policy set here. Default policy is PutIfAbsentMapMergePolicy

            There are built-in merge policies such as
            com.hazelcast.map.merge.PassThroughMergePolicy; entry will be overwritten if merging entry exists for the key.
            com.hazelcast.map.merge.PutIfAbsentMapMergePolicy ; entry will be added if the merging entry doesn't exist in the cluster.
            com.hazelcast.map.merge.HigherHitsMapMergePolicy ; entry with the higher hits wins.
            com.hazelcast.map.merge.LatestUpdateMapMergePolicy ; entry with the latest update wins.
        -->
        <merge-policy>com.hazelcast.map.merge.PutIfAbsentMapMergePolicy</merge-policy>

    </map>

    <map name="offheap_map_v1">
        <in-memory-format>NATIVE</in-memory-format>
        <backup-count>1</backup-count>
        <time-to-live-seconds>0</time-to-live-seconds>
        <max-idle-seconds>0</max-idle-seconds>
        <eviction-policy>NONE</eviction-policy>
        <max-size policy="PER_NODE">0</max-size>
        <eviction-percentage>25</eviction-percentage>
        <merge-policy>com.hazelcast.map.merge.LatestUpdateMapMergePolicy</merge-policy>
    </map>

    <map name="__vertx.subs">
        <backup-count>1</backup-count>
        <time-to-live-seconds>0</time-to-live-seconds>
        <max-idle-seconds>0</max-idle-seconds>
        <eviction-policy>NONE</eviction-policy>
        <max-size policy="PER_NODE">0</max-size>
        <eviction-percentage>25</eviction-percentage>
        <merge-policy>com.hazelcast.map.merge.LatestUpdateMapMergePolicy</merge-policy>
    </map>

    <multimap name="default">
        <backup-count>1</backup-count>
        <value-collection-type>SET</value-collection-type>
    </multimap>

    <list name="default">
        <backup-count>1</backup-count>
    </list>

    <set name="default">
        <backup-count>1</backup-count>
    </set>

    <jobtracker name="default">
        <max-thread-size>0</max-thread-size>
        <!-- Queue size 0 means number of partitions * 2 -->
        <queue-size>0</queue-size>
        <retry-count>0</retry-count>
        <chunk-size>1000</chunk-size>
        <communicate-stats>true</communicate-stats>
        <topology-changed-strategy>CANCEL_RUNNING_OPERATION</topology-changed-strategy>
    </jobtracker>

    <semaphore name="default">
        <initial-permits>0</initial-permits>
        <backup-count>1</backup-count>
        <async-backup-count>0</async-backup-count>
    </semaphore>

    <semaphore name="__vertx.*">
        <initial-permits>1</initial-permits>
    </semaphore>

    <reliable-topic name="default">
        <read-batch-size>10</read-batch-size>
        <topic-overload-policy>BLOCK</topic-overload-policy>
        <statistics-enabled>true</statistics-enabled>
    </reliable-topic>

    <ringbuffer name="default">
        <capacity>10000</capacity>
        <backup-count>1</backup-count>
        <async-backup-count>0</async-backup-count>
        <time-to-live-seconds>30</time-to-live-seconds>
        <in-memory-format>BINARY</in-memory-format>
    </ringbuffer>

    <serialization>
        <portable-version>0</portable-version>
    </serialization>

    <services enable-defaults="true"/>

    <native-memory enabled="true" allocator-type="POOLED">
        <size value="2" unit="GIGABYTES"/>
    </native-memory>

    <properties>
        <property name="hazelcast.version.check.enabled">false</property>
        <property name="hazelcast.elastic.memory.unsafe.enabled">true</property>
        <property name="hazelcast.elastic.memory.enabled">true</property>
        <property name="hazelcast.elastic.memory.total.size">2G</property>      
    </properties>

</hazelcast>
```

Using Hazelcast Java client, I create a demo application to put data to map **offheap_map_v1**. After put about 2 million entries, open Hazelcast Mancenter, i see that "Native memory used is always zero KB".
[image]

My Java source code:

```
import com.hazelcast.client.HazelcastClient;
import com.hazelcast.client.config.ClientConfig;
import com.hazelcast.config.NativeMemoryConfig;
import com.hazelcast.core.HazelcastInstance;
import com.hazelcast.core.IMap;
import com.hazelcast.memory.MemorySize;
import com.hazelcast.memory.MemoryUnit;

public class HazelcastDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ClientConfig clientConfig = new ClientConfig();
        clientConfig.getGroupConfig().setName("dev").setPassword("dev-pass");
        clientConfig.getNetworkConfig().addAddress("192.168.56.1:5701");
        HazelcastInstance client = HazelcastClient.newHazelcastClient(clientConfig);
        IMap<String, String> testMap = client.getMap("offheap_map_v1");

        System.out.print ("Starting ....");
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000000000; i++) {
            testMap.put("key-" + i, "value is " + i);
        }
        System.out.println ("Done!");
    }
}
```

Even when i choose configuring programmatically as

```
import com.hazelcast.client.HazelcastClient;
import com.hazelcast.client.config.ClientConfig;
import com.hazelcast.config.NativeMemoryConfig;
import com.hazelcast.core.HazelcastInstance;
import com.hazelcast.core.IMap;
import com.hazelcast.memory.MemorySize;
import com.hazelcast.memory.MemoryUnit;

public class HazelcastDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MemorySize memorySize = new MemorySize(4, MemoryUnit.GIGABYTES);
        NativeMemoryConfig nativeMemoryConfig =
                new NativeMemoryConfig()
                        .setAllocatorType(NativeMemoryConfig.MemoryAllocatorType.POOLED)
                        .setSize(memorySize)
                        .setEnabled(true)
                        .setMinBlockSize(16)
                        .setPageSize(1 << 20);

        ClientConfig clientConfig = new ClientConfig();
        clientConfig.setNativeMemoryConfig(nativeMemoryConfig);

        clientConfig.getGroupConfig().setName("dev").setPassword("dev-pass");
        clientConfig.getNetworkConfig().addAddress("192.168.56.1:5701");
        HazelcastInstance client = HazelcastClient.newHazelcastClient(clientConfig);
        IMap<String, String> testMap = client.getMap("offheap_map_v1");

        System.out.print ("Starting ....");
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000000000; i++) {
            testMap.put("key-" + i, "value is " + i);
        }
        System.out.println ("Done!");
    }
}
```

Another problem is that after put about 2.000.000 entries, Hazelcast enterprise server is stopped by exception:

```
com.hazelcast.memory.NativeOutOfMemoryError: Queue has 0 available chunks. Data requires 1 chunks. Storage is full!
        at com.hazelcast.elasticmemory.IntegerQueue.poll(IntegerQueue.java:50)
        at com.hazelcast.elasticmemory.UnsafeStorage.reserve(UnsafeStorage.java:176)
        at com.hazelcast.elasticmemory.UnsafeStorage.put(UnsafeStorage.java:97)
        at com.hazelcast.elasticmemory.UnsafeStorage.put(UnsafeStorage.java:33)
        at com.hazelcast.map.impl.record.NativeRecordWithStats.setValue(NativeRecordWithStats.java:59)
        at com.hazelcast.map.impl.record.NativeRecordWithStats.<init>(NativeRecordWithStats.java:34)
        at com.hazelcast.map.impl.record.NativeRecordFactory.newRecord(NativeRecordFactory.java:50)
        at com.hazelcast.map.impl.MapContainer.createRecord(MapContainer.java:194)
        at com.hazelcast.map.impl.AbstractRecordStore.createRecord(AbstractRecordStore.java:97)
        at com.hazelcast.map.impl.DefaultRecordStore.put(DefaultRecordStore.java:793)
        at com.hazelcast.map.impl.operation.PutOperation.run(PutOperation.java:34)
        at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.OperationRunnerImpl.run(OperationRunnerImpl.java:137)
        at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationexecutor.classic.ClassicOperationExecutor.runOnCallingThread(ClassicOperationExecutor.java:380)
        at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationexecutor.classic.ClassicOperationExecutor.runOnCallingThreadIfPossible(ClassicOperationExecutor.java:342)
        at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.Invocation.doInvokeLocal(Invocation.java:247)
        at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.Invocation.doInvoke(Invocation.java:231)
        at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.Invocation.invokeInternal(Invocation.java:198)
        at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:168)
        at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.InvocationBuilderImpl.invoke(InvocationBuilderImpl.java:51)
        at com.hazelcast.client.impl.client.PartitionClientRequest.process(PartitionClientRequest.java:58)
        at com.hazelcast.client.impl.ClientEngineImpl$ClientPacketProcessor.processRequest(ClientEngineImpl.java:468)
        at com.hazelcast.client.impl.ClientEngineImpl$ClientPacketProcessor.run(ClientEngineImpl.java:384)
        at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.OperationRunnerImpl.run(OperationRunnerImpl.java:100)
        at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationexecutor.classic.OperationThread.processPartitionSpecificRunnable(OperationThread.java:130)
        at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationexecutor.classic.OperationThread.process(OperationThread.java:120)
        at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationexecutor.classic.OperationThread.doRun(OperationThread.java:101)
        at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationexecutor.classic.OperationThread.run(OperationThread.java:76)
```

[image]

Did anybody meet the case and can give me an advice?

Thanks and best regards,

Comment: Used Hazelcast Enterprise Trial License Key?

Comment: Yes. I use the trial license key.

Comment: Colleague just told me you're using IMap, anyhow HD Memory for IMap was just introduced with Hazelcast 3.6. Please update to 3.6.1. and try again :) Sorry haven't realized you were trying to use the IMap.

Comment: I use [vertx 3.2.1](http://vertx.io) which uses Hazelcast 3.5.2. To upgrade to 3.6.1, I have to change vertx core modules. I will try with Map instead of IMap. Thank you, noctarius

Comment: Sorry, I missunderstood your idea. Seem that Hazelcast 3.5.2 does not support IMap native memory. I tried to use ICache (Hazelcast demo folder code-samples/enterprise/hd-memory-client-server) and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Just to answer the question in a real way:
Hazelcast up to 3.6 does not support HD Memory Store for IMap, only on JCache. Starting with 3.6, IMap is available too.